# Did Yahoo geocoding stop working?

Tags: geocoding

Geocoding used to work fine, but I discovered today that some contacts added within the last week or two hadn't been geocoded.  I tried editing the addresses manually, and tried running a scheduled / batch job, but the geocoding still didn't happen.

I changed the geocoding provider from Yahoo to Google, and now it works, which is good enough for me.  But I wanted to put this out there in case there's a systemic problem.

Answer (score 1):

Norris, I think you might be right. I was just testing some code and dumped out the raw response from the Yahoo geocoder and got this message:

> geo.placefinder table is no longer supported

Might be time to revisit our Yahoo integration.

Comment: I created an issue for this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19784.